# Sphero Connectivity Issues With Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-8.1, sphero-api, sphero

BACKGROUND:
I am an amateur programmer in my Freshman year of college. We are currently doing a project where we are to take the Sphero and develop a new target market for a more profitable product. Seeing as I am the only one interested in programming, I was chosen as the only programmer of my 4-man team.

QUESTION:
When I connect to the sphero via bluetooth on my laptop, everything goes well until I attempt to run my code I have created. Than I realize that the sphero is no longer connected. When I go to "View Devices" the Sphero is there, however its status is 'not connected'. How can I fix this?

THINGS I HAVE TRIED:
1.) Redownloading / Updating drivers
2.) Uninstalling / Reinstalling device
3.) Restarting

Any assistance you could give would be awesome! Thank you very much for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows after you pair a device it doesn't switch to "connected" until a device actually initiates a connection via established protocol.  In the example of sphero this would be via rfcomm over serial.  When a connection is active it will switch to 'connected' otherwise it is just idling waiting for a connection.